# Activity indicator in SDWebimage placeholder

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimageview, xcode5

How can I set an Activity indicator in `SDWebImage` placeholder using `UIImageView`

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
imgView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
imgView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL))
```

Tested and working

**Swift 5**

```
imgView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5 & SDWebImage 5-beta**

```
//pod file
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0.0-beta3'

//import 
import SDWebImage
```

and set indicator and image

```
myImageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://url", completed: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess its too late but here is a solution for anyone still looking.
The SDWebImage library includes it by default.

Works like a charm for me :

Swift 3:

```
imgView.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
imgView.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Updates for Swift 5 : SDWebImage 5.x.x

```
imgView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Comment: I m using SDWebImage 5.0.2. Unfortunately it doesnt have these methods

Comment: Please find the updates. Kindly upvote if it wokrs for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**SdWebImage 5.0**

```
YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    extension UIViewController{

    func setUpBackGroundImage (imageUrl : String,finish: @escaping ((image:UIImage, error:Error?)) -> Void){
    let networkIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var result:(image:UIImage, error:Error?) = (image:UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "game_bg"),error :nil)
    networkIndicator.center = view.center
    networkIndicator.style = .whiteLarge
    networkIndicator.startAnimating()
    view.addSubview(networkIndicator)
    if imageUrl != ""{
        SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(
            with: URL(string: imageUrl),
            options: .highPriority,
            progress: nil) { (image, data, error, cacheType, isFinished, imageUrl) in
                print(isFinished)
                networkIndicator.stopAnimating()
                networkIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                 if (error != nil) {
                    result.error = error!
                 }else{
                    result.image = image!
                }                    
            finish(result)
          }
      }
    }
 }
```

Usage :

```
     setUpBackGroundImage(imageUrl: backgroundImageURL, finish: { (arg0) in
        let (image, error) = arg0
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (error != nil) {
                self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "game_bg")
            } else {
                self.backgroundImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, SDWebImage 5.15.8**

To show activity indicator:

```swift
imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.grayLarge
imageView.sd_imageIndicator?.startAnimatingIndicator()
```

Once image is downloaded, just stop it:

```swift
imageView.sd_imageIndicator?.stopAnimatingIndicator()
```

Answer (score 0):

`[indicator startAnimating];`//indicator start animating

```
    //Load image
[imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) 
    {

         [indicator stopAnimating]; //indicator stop animating after image load

    }];
```

Comment: Where I should place the indicator ?

Comment: use the indicator on uiimageview.

Comment: [_newsimage addSubview:activityIndicator];
[_newsimage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {
         
         [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
         
     }];

// I am trying to do like this !

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple way you can add the activity indicator. you can also chnage color of indicator check below code

```
import SDWebImage
```

imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
imgProfileOnTop.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: obj?.profileImg ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(name:"placeholderImage"))

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.